Issue extending NUnit's Is
I'm currently trying to extend NUnit's Is class, but I've run into a wall. I've got it mostly functional already, but strangely only if my extension isn't inside a namespace. Furthermore, even when it does work, I cannot use things like Is.Not. I followed the guide of both the official documentation and a tutorial (and searched Google), to no avail. Do you guys have any pointers to find and correct my both the namespace and Is.Not issue(s)?
Any follow-up questions are welcome.
The extension class, including the namespace:
namespace DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Constraints
{
    public class Is : NUnit.Framework.Is
    {
        public static VectorConstraint OnSameTile(object expected)
        {
            return new VectorConstraint(expected);
        }
    }
}

The class which should enable me to use Is.Not.
namespace DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Constraints
{
    public static class CustomConstraintExtensions
    {
        public static VectorConstraint OnTile(this ConstraintExpression expression, object expected)
        {
            VectorConstraint constraint = new VectorConstraint(expected);
            expression.Append(constraint);
            return constraint;
        }
    }
}

Mockup of the test
using System.Numerics;
using DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Constraints;

namespace DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Tests
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Vector2 firstVector = new Vector2(1, 1);
            Vector2 secondVector = new Vector2(1, 1);

            // When extension method is in namespace: 'Is' is an ambiguous reference between 'DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Counstraints.Is' and 'NUnit.Framework.Is'
            // Otherwise, executes as expected. I do want to put it in a namespace however.
            Assert.That(firstVector, Is.OnSameTile(secondVector));

            // When extension method is not in a namespace, I still cannot use Is.Not and receive the following compile error:
            // 'ConstraintExpression' does not contain a definition for 'OnSameTile' and no accessible extension method 'OnSameTile' accepting a first argument of type 'ConstraintExpression' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
            Assert.That(firstVector, Is.Not.OnSameTile(secondVector));
        }
    }
}

My constraint. Don't think it's relevant, but just for reference.
namespace DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Constraints
{
    public class VectorConstraint : Constraint
    {
        public object Expected { get; }

        public VectorConstraint(object expected)
        {
            Expected = expected;
        }

        public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual)
        {
            // Comparison code here
        }
    }
}


Edit1: Made some progress. The Is.Not is simply not working, because the method in CustomConstraintExtensions was called 'OnTile', rather than 'OnSameTile'.
I've also discovered that the Is extension Class, rather than needing to be namespace-less, must be in the same namespace as or in a parent namespace of the test Class. Which I find strange, as no such restriction applies to other extension Classes in my project.
Edit2: The test mockup didn't include the "using DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Constraints;", which was included in my actual test. Updated it to better reflect it.

I doubt that it needs to be in the same namespace as the test class, but if it is not, you need to add a corresponding using directive so that the compiler can find it.

No, this was unfortunately just me being dumb and forgetting to include it in the mockup... My actual tests do include a using statement to the namespace and will update the question to reflect this. However, as stated in my first edit, I do have it fully functional now when my extension Method is in the DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests namespace. However, I am still quite confused as to why this is.

There are two problems in your code:

You called your extension method for ConstraintExpression "OnTile" rather than "OnSameTile." In order for the fluent syntax to work in a way that makes sense, the static method you add to Is and the extension method for ConstraintExpression must have the same name.

You are not referencing the namespaces in which you created both methods in your test class. That requires two using statements because you placed those methods in two different namespaces. Using the same namespace for both would make things a little simpler. To make it even simpler, put them in a namespace you are already using. Another option is to create a namespace like NUnit.Framework.MyCustomExtensions and reference that namespace in place of NUnit.Framework. Whatever you do, your compiler will tell you if you got it right. :-)



Thank you for your reply!

I did eventually figure this one out as seen in my edit :)



No, unfortunately this is just me being dumb and forgetting to include it in the mockup... My actual tests do include a using statement to the namespace and will update the question to reflect this. However, as stated in my first edit, I do have it fully functional now when my extension Method is in the DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests namespace. However, I am still quite confused as to why this is. Also, I did test your suggestion of using the NUnit.Framework.MyCustomExtensions namespace, which unfortunately left me with the same error as using DFA_Lib_Unit_Tests.Constraints.

